# How to store each database in a different directory

Tags: couchdb

The [CouchDB base configuration](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/couchdb.html) allows setting of the directory where databases are stored, like so:

```
 database_dir = /path/to/the/databases
```

But I want to store each database in a different directory. Is this possible? Are there any workarounds to make this possible if it's not supported out-the-box? Are there other NoSQL databases that do support this?

Answer (score 3):

Use a `%2f` in your database name to achieve this:

```
dch  http put $COUCH/dir%2fsubdb
dch  tree ~/couchdb/dbs
/Users/dch/couchdb/dbs
├── _replicator.couch
├── _users.couch
└─── dir/
    └── subdb.couch
```

IIRC this should survive compaction.

A better question would be "why do you want to put your DBs in separate folders"? It's not visible to the user, and they're already in different files. What's the advantage? Would you put each table in a SQL database in its own directory too?

Comment: For me this question is interesting because I'm researching for a system that might benefit from having 3-4 databases per user, and that should be capable of a lot of users. This results in a lot of files (and bad perf) in one directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to update the [couchdb config file on the fly](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/server/configuration.html#put--_config-section-key) but I think it will break couchdb if you do it.

A solution could be to run multiple couchdb instances. couchdb is pretty light weight only requiring 19 mb of memory when it has nothing in it [1] Each couchdb could point to a different directory of your choice. But rather than having multiple couchdb running and waiting it would be a lot better if you could commission a couch to run  for you. For that you will need a vm. [erlang on xen](http://erlangonxen.org/) sounds perfect for this task since couchdb is written in erlang. Though you will have to experiment a bit as there are non erlang parts in there too. If that does not work there is always docker.

[1] According to the lazy monday afternoon experiments that I ran. Conduct your own to be sure :)

Comment: CouchDB will *not* run on EoX (sadly) as it has several C-based dependencies, and relies heavily on piping over std OS processes for javascript functionality.
Updating the config on the fly like this will simply cause the universe to implode. Views will need to be rebuilt, I can't imagine what else would go haywire.
You can use the %2f trick in a database name, which I'll add in its own answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't create a lot of dbs, you can manually move them in your destination directory and symlink to them (it's not strictly needed, but I guessed it's safer to stop couchdb before).

Even better, if you already know your dbs, you can do this process before even starting couchdb:

```
$ touch /path/to/realfiles/db
```

or

```
$ mv /path/to/couchfiles/existingdb /path/to/realfiles/db
```

and then, in both cases:

```
$ ln -s /path/to/realfiles/db /path/to/couchfiles
```

After starting up and receiving a query for this db, couchdb will automatically format the db in the expected internal format and you can start using it.

Comment: This is not advised, it breaks compaction.